# Can LINQ support this simple algorithm?

Tags: c#, linq

I've been trying to learn LINQ, and I'm wondering if there is a way for LINQ to perform the following:

I have a list of objects that consume data from an array in a serial fashion. I am trying to do two things with one loop:

1. Use the input array to populate the objects serially with data where each object consumes a different amount of data.
2. Keep track of "Index" which tells me how much data has been consumed.

Here is an example with code:

```
class MyBase {
    virtual int ReadData(int[] array, int StartingIndex) { }
}

class Derived1 : MyBase {
    int a;

    public override int ReadData(int[] array, int StartIndex) {
       a = array[StartingIndex];
       return StartingIndex + 1;
    }
}

class Derived2 : MyBase {
    int a, b;

    public override int ReadData(int[] array, int StartIndex) {
        a = array[StartingIndex];
        b = array[StartingIndex + 1];
        return StartingIndex + 2;
    }
}

class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        MyBase[] array = new MyBase[] {
           new Derived1(),
           new Derived2(),
           new Derived1()
        }

        int[] input = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };          
        int Index = 0 
        for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++) {
            Index = array[i].ReadData(input, Index);
        }
    }
}
```

The end result is that these objects have the following values:

> `Object 0 has the val 1`
>     `Object 1 has the val 2 and 3`
>     `Object 2 has the val 4`

But I can't figure out how to do this with LINQ.

Comment: You're calling methods that effectively has side effects, while you can express it using LINQ, _you shouldn't_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A LINQish way to do this (rather than just a LINQish way to write the `for` loop) is to pass the array on to each method and have it take what it needs and return the rest. You won't have the final index in hand, but you will have the *remainder*:

```
MyBase[] array = new MyBase[] { new Derived1() , new Derived2(), new Derived1()}
int [] input = new int[] { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};

IEnumerable<int> unusedInputs = input;
foreach (MyBase entity in array)
{
     unusedInputs = entity.ReadData(unusedInputs);
}
```

and your ReadData code goes like this:

```
public override IEnumerable<int> ReadData( IEnumerable<int> data) 
{
    a = data.Take(1).Single();
    return Data.Skip(1);
}

public override IEnumerable<int> ReadData( IEnumerable<int> data) 
{
    var dataRead = data.Take(2);
    a = dataRead.First();
    b = dataRead.Skip(1).First();
    return data.Skip(2);
}
```